# Footer not showing up even on inspect element after completing my php email form

Tags: php, html, css

I added a PHP mail form to my website, upon page load after completing the email form my footer is not loaded the tags do not even show up in inspect element.
I have the pages linked below. 
edit:footer only doesn't appear when there are errors when it is submitted.

Before and after form submission where you can see the footer
http://andytest.herokuapp.com/contact.php

Any help is appreciated because I have no idea why it is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The footer is showing for me and this CSS class is applied to it:

```
#footer {
    background-image: url("../../images/bottombar2.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and this is your footer code (using firebug)

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </footer>
```

[image]

as I can see you are using HTML5 `<footer>` tag maybe you are viewing your site with a non compatible html5 browser.
or maybe you want to set a white background for your footer as same as your menu then just update your css like this:

```
#footer {
    background-color:white;
    border-top:2px solid orange;
    clear: both;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have attached the screen shot. After clicking on the submit button (I tried twice) and I got the same result. I could see the footer.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear the footer only doesn't show on the page when the form is not filled out correctly and shows the errors that need to be fixed.

Comment: can you paste the code for send_form_email.php I think you are not generating the codes properly.. I need to have a look at your code.I used firebug to add the footer code and your menu shows up properly so definitely you are missing it somewhere in the code.

Comment: I also check my browsers to make sure they are up to date.They are up to date was the error is on both Firefox and chrome which which are the 2 I checked it on.
Yes I can paste it.

Comment: http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php 
This is the email form I am using .

Comment: I need to see your PHP code the one which you are using on your site.<br> please send the code for send_form_email.php

Comment: Besides the code which I dropped straight in this is the page -css links and metadata

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

  </head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div id=header-bg></div>
  </header>
<div id=wrapper>
  <?php include "~/components/php/header.php"; ?>
  
  <div id=content>
    <div id="mainContent">
      
      </div><!--mainContent-->
    <div id="sideBar">
    </div><!--sidebar-->
  </div ><!--content-->
</div><!--wrapper-->
<footer>
  <div id=footer></div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

Comment: It was placed in the sidebar section
Thank you for your time and Patience

Comment: I never edited the PHP so It's just as shown on the website just dropped into a div

Comment: I found the error the page was gettign killed before it could finish loading by the die(); in the program  stopping the page from finish loading. Thanks for the help and leading me in the right direction saying it was in the php.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error the page was getting killed before it could finish loading by the die(); which stopped the page from finish loading. Thanks for the help and leading me in the right direction saying it was in the php